# Null.Pointer Exception is getting when i calling from php

Tags: soap, php

I am receiving a null reference exception when this webservice is called from php. I am unable to resolve this on my own.

My Webservice code

```
global class Ctest{
  global class RequestClass{
        webservice String accName; 
  }

global class ResponseClass{
    webservice String errorMessage;
    webservice String resName;
 }  

    webservice static ResponseClass behaviourOfWebService(RequestClass req)
    {

        ResponseClass res = new ResponseClass();
        Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
        List<Account> lstAccount = new List<Account>();
        lstAccount = [Select Id,Name from Account where Name =: req.accName];
           Account a = new Account();
            **a.Name = req.accName;** ERROR OCCURING POINT
           try
           { 
            insert a;
           }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
              Database.rollback(sp);
              res.errorMessage = 'ERROR_CREATING_ACCOUNT: ' + e.getMessage();
               return res;
          } 

           res.resName = a.Name;
           return res;
      }

     }
```

When i Use below webservice it is working from php May i know what is problem in above webservice if i use requestclass at that it is not working.and showing null pointer exception at this line a.Name = req.accName

```
global class Ctest {

  webservice static void  cInsert(String accName){
       Account a1 = new Account();
       a1.Name = accName;
       insert a1;
   }
}
```

[image: Debug LOg]

Comment: Could you please make your code more readable and add some more details ? When and where does the null reference occurs, what have you already tried to debug this ? .. help us help you.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke i modified my question i am getting a.Name = req.accName at this line

Comment: Formatting your code greatly improves readability. Could you try doing that yourself ? It doesn't hurt to put some effort into your questions :)

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke i modified my code once check it.

Comment: I've made an attempt to make your question easier to read. Doing this yourself may help you get your answers faster. Just dumping the code does not motivate people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be blanking out what is being passed into the method.

```
webservice static ResponseClass behaviourOfWebService(RequestClass req)
{
    req = new RequestClass();
```

This is basically accepting the RequestClass to be passed into your method... then you are creating a new blank instance of it.

Comment: May i know where i have to do modifications in my code

Comment: Suppose if i remove req=new RequestClass() this line also i am getting same error.

Comment: .May i know where i have to modify my code.

Comment: That should be the line you need to remove.  Right before your error can you do System.debug('req = ' + req); and tell me what this value might be?  You are likely passing a null value into this method.

Comment: i add the image of debuglog.

Comment: my print is showing is req = null in debug log

Comment: Ok, the issue shouldn't be with the rest of your SFDC code.   It appears you are either passing nothing at all OR invalid data into this method.  You might need to make changes to your PHP to make sure you are sending the correct data.

Comment: shall i provide php code can you give any suggestions

Comment: Might be a good idea.  I'm not strong in my PHP but I might be able to notice what you are doing wrong with the request.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13129/discussion-between-sathya-and-dphil)

Answer (score -1):

Man, are you kidding us???
What is wrong with checking req for null??? I told you that in previous question. Maybe you should learn Basic or Pascal as a start?

Surround

```
a.Name = req.accName;
```

with if statement

```
if(req != null) { a.Name = req.accName; }
```

Comment: i did not solve my issuse..

Comment: I don't think that was his issue.  He needs to figure out exactly why the request he is sending sends a null value when he is clearly sending something not null.  My guess is that it is somehow a wrong type or something.